# ¿Por qué hay conflictos entre las cabeceras y el programa que las implementa?

Tags: c

Dadas las siguientes cabeceras:

(1) **pilainfo.h**

```
/*
 * Este tipo define la información que contiene la pila (el contenido)
 */
typedef struct pilainfo
{
     int id;
     char matricula[10];
     char dni[10];
     char nombre[50];
     char mail[50];
     float nota;
} tdata;
```

(2) **pilavector.h**

```
#define MAXPILA 50

#include "pilainfo.h"

/*
 * El tipo pilavector define la pila y el indice a la cima
 * Se accederá mediante los habituales servicios push/pop
 */
typedef struct pilavector {
   tdata datos[MAXPILA];
   int top;
} tpv;
```

Dado **prueba.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "pilainfo.h"
#include "pilavector.h"

tpv pv;
```

Si intentan compilar, verán que saltan bastantes errores. Se dividen en **dos tipos de errores**: los primeros en saltar son de **redefinición** de variables y los segundos sobre **conflicto** de tipos. Estoy seguro de que **los segundos son consecuencia directa de los primeros**.

[image: Error C]

Los primeros parecen surgir debido a algún tipo de **conflicto con las cabeceras**, pero no entiendo qué está mal. Las cabeceras están definidas correctamente e incluidas correctamente en prueba.c.

Este problema me ha surgido en un programa mayor donde *pilavector.h* presenta, además, cabeceras de métodos que luego hay que desarrollar dentro de prueba.c. A su vez, prueba.c servirá como programa auxiliar a otro mayor que es el que dirige toda la ejecución, es decir, el que tiene el main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error se produce porque no estás utilizando guardas en tus cabeceras.

Una cabecera típica de C debe tener la siguiente forma:

```
#ifndef [ID_CABECERA]
#define [ID_CABECERA]

// Código de la cabecera

#endif
```

En algunos casos también te lo puedes encontrar así:

```
#pragma once

// Código de la cabecera
```

La diferencia básica entre ambos ejemplos es que el primero es una solución *estándar* que funcionará siempre mientras que el segundo podría no funcionar en algunos compiladores.

Las directivas en rodean el código de la cabecera (en el primer caso) evitan que la propia cabecera se incluya varias veces en el código. Esto se hace así porque se evitan numerosos errores de compilación:

- Includes recursivos (A incluye B que a su vez incluye a A)
- Redefinición de funciones y estructuras

Pero, ¿por qué se producen estos errores?

Para entenderlo hay que comprender antes cómo funciona el proceso de compilación en C.

Cuando intentamos compilar un archivo en C, lo primero que entra en acción es el preprocesador. Este programa recorre el archivo y reemplaza todas las directivas del preprocesador por otra cosa:

- Las directivas condicionales `#ifdef`, `#endif` eliminarán el código que contienen si no se cumple la condición
- Las macros `#define` se reemplazan por el código correspondiente

  ```
  #define SUM(a, b) a+b
  int c = SUM(1, 3); -> int c = 1+3;
  ```
- Los includes se reemplazan por el archivo al que enlazan

Este proceso se repite hasta que no quede ninguna directiva de preprocesador en el código.

Es decir, en tu caso, en el archivo `prueba.c` sucederá lo siguiente:

Código original:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "pilainfo.h"
#include "pilavector.h"

tpv pv;
```

Se reemplaza el primer include:

```
// contenido de stdio.h ...

#include "pilainfo.h"
#include "pilavector.h"

tpv pv;
```

Se reemplaza el segundo include:

```
// contenido de stdio.h ...

/*
 * Este tipo define la información que contiene la pila (el contenido)
 */
typedef struct pilainfo
{
     int id;
     char matricula[10];
     char dni[10];
     char nombre[50];
     char mail[50];
     float nota;
} tdata;
#include "pilavector.h"

tpv pv;
```

Se reemplaza el tercer include:

```
// contenido de stdio.h ...

/*
 * Este tipo define la información que contiene la pila (el contenido)
 */
typedef struct pilainfo
{
     int id;
     char matricula[10];
     char dni[10];
     char nombre[50];
     char mail[50];
     float nota;
} tdata;
#define MAXPILA 50

#include "pilainfo.h"

/*
 * El tipo pilavector define la pila y el indice a la cima
 * Se accederá mediante los habituales servicios push/pop
 */
typedef struct pilavector {
   tdata datos[MAXPILA];
   int top;
} tpv;

tpv pv;
```

Ha aparecido otro include ... se reemplaza:

```
// contenido de stdio.h ...

/*
 * Este tipo define la información que contiene la pila (el contenido)
 */
typedef struct pilainfo
{
     int id;
     char matricula[10];
     char dni[10];
     char nombre[50];
     char mail[50];
     float nota;
} tdata;
#define MAXPILA 50

/*
 * Este tipo define la información que contiene la pila (el contenido)
 */
typedef struct pilainfo
{
     int id;
     char matricula[10];
     char dni[10];
     char nombre[50];
     char mail[50];
     float nota;
} tdata;

/*
 * El tipo pilavector define la pila y el indice a la cima
 * Se accederá mediante los habituales servicios push/pop
 */
typedef struct pilavector {
   tdata datos[MAXPILA];
   int top;
} tpv;

tpv pv;
```

Como ves, ahora tenemos un problema y es que tanto `pilainfo` como `tdata` aparece definido dos veces:

```
// contenido de stdio.h ...

/*
 * Este tipo define la información que contiene la pila (el contenido)
 */
typedef struct pilainfo       // <<---- pilainfo(1)
{
     int id;
     char matricula[10];
     char dni[10];
     char nombre[50];
     char mail[50];
     float nota;
} tdata;                       // <<---- tdata(1)
#define MAXPILA 50

/*
 * Este tipo define la información que contiene la pila (el contenido)
 */
typedef struct pilainfo       // <<---- pilainfo(2)
{
     int id;
     char matricula[10];
     char dni[10];
     char nombre[50];
     char mail[50];
     float nota;
} tdata;                       // <<---- tdata(2)

/*
 * El tipo pilavector define la pila y el indice a la cima
 * Se accederá mediante los habituales servicios push/pop
 */
typedef struct pilavector {
   tdata datos[MAXPILA];
   int top;
} tpv;

tpv pv;
```

Este problema se soluciona definiendo las guardas en las cabeceras:

**pilainfo.h**

```
#ifndef PILAINFO_H
#define PILAINFO_H

/*
 * Este tipo define la información que contiene la pila (el contenido)
 */
typedef struct pilainfo
{
     int id;
     char matricula[10];
     char dni[10];
     char nombre[50];
     char mail[50];
     float nota;
} tdata;

#endif
```

**pilavector.h**

```
#ifndef PILAVECTOR_H
#define PILAVECTOR_H

#define MAXPILA 50

#include "pilainfo.h"

/*
 * El tipo pilavector define la pila y el indice a la cima
 * Se accederá mediante los habituales servicios push/pop
 */
typedef struct pilavector {
   tdata datos[MAXPILA];
   int top;
} tpv;

#endif
```

Ahora el código generado por el preprocesador variará ligeramente:

Código original:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "pilainfo.h"
#include "pilavector.h"

tpv pv;
```

Se reemplaza el primer include:

```
// contenido de stdio.h ...

#include "pilainfo.h"
#include "pilavector.h"

tpv pv;
```

Se reemplaza el segundo include:

```
// contenido de stdio.h ...

#ifndef PILAINFO_H
#define PILAINFO_H

/*
 * Este tipo define la información que contiene la pila (el contenido)
 */
typedef struct pilainfo
{
     int id;
     char matricula[10];
     char dni[10];
     char nombre[50];
     char mail[50];
     float nota;
} tdata;

#endif
#include "pilavector.h"

tpv pv;
```

Se procesa el condicional. Como el símbolo `PILAINFO_H` no está definido, el código permanece:

```
// contenido de stdio.h ...

#define PILAINFO_H

/*
 * Este tipo define la información que contiene la pila (el contenido)
 */
typedef struct pilainfo
{
     int id;
     char matricula[10];
     char dni[10];
     char nombre[50];
     char mail[50];
     float nota;
} tdata;

#include "pilavector.h"

tpv pv;
```

Se reemplaza el tercer include:

```
// contenido de stdio.h ...

#define PILAINFO_H

/*
 * Este tipo define la información que contiene la pila (el contenido)
 */
typedef struct pilainfo
{
     int id;
     char matricula[10];
     char dni[10];
     char nombre[50];
     char mail[50];
     float nota;
} tdata;

#ifndef PILAVECTOR_H
#define PILAVECTOR_H

#define MAXPILA 50

#include "pilainfo.h"

/*
 * El tipo pilavector define la pila y el indice a la cima
 * Se accederá mediante los habituales servicios push/pop
 */
typedef struct pilavector {
   tdata datos[MAXPILA];
   int top;
} tpv;

#endif

tpv pv;
```

Se procesa el condicional. `PILAVECTOR_H` no está definido, luego el código que engloba el condicional permanece intacto:

```
// contenido de stdio.h ...

#define PILAINFO_H

/*
 * Este tipo define la información que contiene la pila (el contenido)
 */
typedef struct pilainfo
{
     int id;
     char matricula[10];
     char dni[10];
     char nombre[50];
     char mail[50];
     float nota;
} tdata;

#define PILAVECTOR_H

#define MAXPILA 50

#include "pilainfo.h"

/*
 * El tipo pilavector define la pila y el indice a la cima
 * Se accederá mediante los habituales servicios push/pop
 */
typedef struct pilavector {
   tdata datos[MAXPILA];
   int top;
} tpv;

tpv pv;
```

Queda un `#include`, se reemplaza:

```
// contenido de stdio.h ...

#define PILAINFO_H

/*
 * Este tipo define la información que contiene la pila (el contenido)
 */
typedef struct pilainfo
{
     int id;
     char matricula[10];
     char dni[10];
     char nombre[50];
     char mail[50];
     float nota;
} tdata;

#define PILAVECTOR_H

#define MAXPILA 50

#ifndef PILAINFO_H
#define PILAINFO_H

/*
 * Este tipo define la información que contiene la pila (el contenido)
 */
typedef struct pilainfo
{
     int id;
     char matricula[10];
     char dni[10];
     char nombre[50];
     char mail[50];
     float nota;
} tdata;

#endif

/*
 * El tipo pilavector define la pila y el indice a la cima
 * Se accederá mediante los habituales servicios push/pop
 */
typedef struct pilavector {
   tdata datos[MAXPILA];
   int top;
} tpv;

tpv pv;
```

Se procesa el condicional. Ahora vemos que el símbolo `PILAINFO_H` ya se encuentra defindo más arriba, luego el condicional desaparecerá sin más:

```
// contenido de stdio.h ...

#define PILAINFO_H

/*
 * Este tipo define la información que contiene la pila (el contenido)
 */
typedef struct pilainfo
{
     int id;
     char matricula[10];
     char dni[10];
     char nombre[50];
     char mail[50];
     float nota;
} tdata;

#define PILAVECTOR_H

#define MAXPILA 50

/*
 * El tipo pilavector define la pila y el indice a la cima
 * Se accederá mediante los habituales servicios push/pop
 */
typedef struct pilavector {
   tdata datos[MAXPILA];
   int top;
} tpv;

tpv pv;
```

Como ves, esto hace que el símbolo que estaba repetido ya no lo esté, evitando los errores de compilación que se te estaban generando.

Comment: En la guarda, ¿por qué el nombre del archivo de la cabecera va en mayúsculas? En este caso, PILAINFO_H

Comment: @SergioDuránVega Por norma, los identificadores de las macros se escriben en mayúsculas. `#ifndef` y `#define` reciben un identificador de macro ... de ahí que esos valores suelan estar en mayúsculas. No obstante puedes poner ahí lo que quieras siempre y cuando los identificadores para cada archivo sean únicos y cuidando que dichos identificadores no coincidan con código que escribas ... en ese caso el preprocesador reemplazará tu código

Comment: Una respuesta perfecta. Muchas gracias por su tiempo, EFERION